# How to get result from `filter` by `return`ing the result?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to return a filtered result. But I am getting the jQuery object instead of the length.

Is there a way to do this?

```
var userNoteClass = spans.filter(function(index) {
    return this.className.split(' ').reduce(function(cNum, cName) {
        return cName.substring(0, 8) === 'userNote' ? cNum + 1 : cNum;
    }, 0).length; //i required the cNum to be consoled out.
});

console.log(userNoteClass); // length i am looking here..
```

Comment: Can we get some sample HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is not filtering. You need `Array.map`.

```
var userNoteClass = spans.map(function(index) {
    return this.className.split(' ').reduce(function(cNum, cName) {
        return cName.substring(0, 8) === 'userNote' ? cNum + 1 : cNum;
    }, 0); // leave it as it is
});
console.log(userNoteClass);
```

Reduce function is returning a Number, so there's no need of `length`, I suppose.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: @BhojendraNepal yeah. It's built-in.

Comment: I am getting result like this, `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[5], context: undefined, jquery: "1.11.1", constructor: function, selector: ""…]` not the number. and i am passing jQuery object not array.